Grep’s result coloring, and right-to-left scripts
I have a text file with a single line that contains the single Yiddish word azoy, in Hebrew script: אַזױ. Then I grep for occurrences of the oy character, ױ.
(This is highly simplified of course, in reality it’s not so trivial.)
By default, grep (I run it under Lubuntu 23.10) colors its results. When I disable that, everything works fine:
grep --color=never ױ filewithazoy
correctly finds and displays: אַזױ
But when I do not disable result coloring, the oy character is displayed correctly in red, but IN THE WRONG order: ױאַז
I suppose this is caused by the escape sequences for rendering the colors: they contain an m and a K. Apparently Unicode’s birectional algorithm is applied BEFORE interpreting the escape sequences, so the presence of Latin characters messes up the order of the Hebrew characters. I think it should be the other way round: render the colors from the escape sequences, and THEN apply the directional algorithm on the Hebrew only result. But that’s probably easier said than done.
What I tried, without success:

Install a he_IL locale, and activate it for qterminal and bash.
The same, but with not only LC_ALL, but also LANG and LANGUAGE set to Hebrew.
Run grep with color=always, so it sends coloring also into a pipe. I wrote a little C program that adds Unicode characters 200f (right to left mark) before and after the line.
The same, but that last one just before the newline, not after it.
The same with a 202e (right-to-left override) at the beginning of the line.

Nothing worked for me.
How do people in Israel do this? Or those working with Yiddish in New York etc.?

Does it work any better on GNOME Terminal (or some other terminal that is not based on QTermWidget)? Few if any have good support for bidirectional text, but something based around libvte would be my next thing to try.

Interesting point, thanks for suggesting it.
I tried to run Ubuntu 24.04 live, and Debian 12 Gnome edition under KVM/QEMA in Lubuntu. But neither would boot, so I didn't manage to try out Gnome terminal.

I mean, you don't have to boot a completely different distro to try out something that's already available for install from Ubuntu repository... The version I have on Arch seems to work better (at least when testing this one example) – Ubuntu 23.10 will have a somewhat older libvte, but it still might be recent enough to do the job.

Wait, much simpler and faster: gnome-terminal can be installed as a separate program under Lubuntu. I did, ran the test, and ... tada ...
it works correctly!!!

KDE’s konsole also does it right. So the problem seems to be restricted to LXQt’s qterminal.
